# What happens to spin when bosons exchange bosons?

Tags: angular-momentum, conservation-laws, quantum-spin, standard-model, bosons

I understand that spin is a conserved quantity, I also understand that gluons can exchange gluons, and $W$ bosons exchange photons. However, when I try to combine these concepts, I can't figure out what spin is doing. It seems to require particles to momentarily have 0 spin (or 2 spin), and two bosons be exchanged. So, I was wondering what actually happens to the spin of particles in the exchange.

The reason I got that 0 spin must occur during the process, and two bosons be exchanged, is because when say a $W$ boson releases a photon its spin will either be 0 or 2, and the same for the other $W$ boson it is exchanging with (with the opposite 0 or 2), in order for this to go back to normal another photon has to be exchanged either from the other $W$ boson, or the original $W$ boson. This somewhat assumes the $W$ bosons both have +1 spin, and not opposite spin.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "when say a  boson releases a photon its spin will either be 0 or 2"... Whose spin? Where did this come from? Why? Show your work.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Say we have a W boson, if it releases a photon its own spin must be 0 or 2. It will have 0 spin if it releases a photon with spin 1, and will have spin 2 if it releases a photon with spin -1. Of course this assumes the W boson started with spin 1, and not spin -1. Sorry I wasn't clear, is there anything else unclear?

Comment: Your basic premise that you may not have a triple coupling of spin 1 particles is false. You may easily have 3-gluon couplings, or WWZ, or WWγ couplings. How do you add spins?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I know it should be possible. I was asking how it was possible, also I am not sure what you question is asking.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. Are you talking about $S$ or $S_z$? there is a serious conceptual disconnect here. Are you in complete control of the idiosyncratic nonabelian composition of spins?